# iOS Framework which can support iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have very simple requirement for my iOS SDK

-Support iOS 7 and above.

-Include some swift code to my SDK

Problems:

-With iOS 8, Xcode allowed us to develop cocoa touch frameworks, but they can only be run on iOS 8 and above.

-If I create a static library, I cannot include swift code.

-I was using using [Real Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework), but Real Framework does not get installed with Xcode 7.

*So, What does a poor developer do ?*

Answer (score 0):

You can always have an alternative distribution method for your SDK for users that are targeting iOS 7.

1. You can offer an SDK in a single concatenated file, that is simply merging all your project source files, which user can drop into project tree and compile together with all the other source files. This applies only when you have either Swift-only or Objective-C only SDK
2. If SDK user uses workspaces, he may embed your SDKs .xcodeproj directly  in his project

Anyway both methods require source code distribution as the user needs to compile the code from within his project. Dependency maintenance is also more difficult.

For a reference you can check how it is done in:
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

It is a Swift library, but integration with iOS 7 based projects is the same.

Comment: I cannot distribute my source code. If I make a SDK on Xcode 6.4, is it safe to include that SDK in an app and submit app to AppStore ?

Comment: You can't distribute source code of app or SDK? I think that since introduction of iOS 9, you have to use Xcode 7 to submit the app to the store. Or didn't I get correctly second part of your question?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any solution for this. I compromised:

- I am NOT using swift code.
- I am distributing static library (.a file and a .h header file) instead of a framework. (this is to support iOS 7)